# matrices comparisons

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, charts, imshow

I'am trying to deal with satellites pictures using python. To summarize I have two big matrices (3000rows - 16 columns) that show satellites informations with value between [0-100]. I would like that each matrice is represent with a specific color.

here is what I do:

```
plt.imshow(viz, cmap='Blues',vmax=100,aspect='auto')
plt.imshow(viz1, cmap='Reds',vmax=100,aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

with viz and viz1 looking like :

```
[(100,0,100,45 ...
  ..  .. .. ..  ..
  0 , 23 , 65 , ...)]
```

[EDIT] my two matrices are satellite pictures. One is the morning the other is the evening. The purpose is to spot the differences

[EDIT] the thing is that sometimes on viz I would have a 0 value and if I substract with wiz1 it will be negative number. I tried the absolute difference but then I loose the informations of the numbe
for example **i would like to see the value that didnt change **from viz 1 in red and viz blue and the value that changed in Orange****

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for your advices , I completely rewrite my questions.

Comment: Still needs a data sample though.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to spot the differences between the two images why not use `imshow` to plot the result of the subtraction of the two matrices:

```
mat_diff=viz-viz1
plt.imshow(mat_diff,aspect='auto')
```

And if you are interested in the absolute difference:

```
mat_abs_diff=abs(viz-viz1)
plt.imshow(mat_abs_diff,aspect='auto')
```

Comment: Hello @jylls , thanks for you answer , the thing is that sometimes on viz I would have a 0 value and if I substract with wiz1 it will be negative number. I tried the absolute difference but then I loose the informations of the number , i cant know if it comes from viz and viz1 ... for example i would like to see the value that didnt change from viz 1 in red and viz blue

Answer (score 0):

Giving this another try. Something you could do is to use the `alpha` argument from your `imshow` function and use it to see the two images superimposed. In the code below I plot two arrays. The first one is the identity matrix and the second one is the `fliplr` version of the identity matrix (opposite diagonal). On top of that, I set the element `mat_2[0,0]=1` to show what it looks like when the two arrays overlap. Here what this looks like on a toy example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N_dim=10
#Creating the two images

#mat_1 is the identity matrix
mat_1=np.diag(N_dim*[1])

#mat_2 is the fliplr version of mat_1 (opposite diagonal)
mat_2=np.diag(N_dim*[1])

#And to create artificial overlap between mat_1 and mat_2, I set the first element [0,0] of mat_2 equal to 1
mat_2=np.fliplr(mat_2)
mat_2[0,0]=1

#imshow with alpha=0.5 to see both images
plt.imshow(mat_1,cmap='Reds',aspect='auto',alpha=0.5)
plt.imshow(mat_2,cmap='Blues',aspect='auto',alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

The first array appears red, the second blue and the mixture purple.